# Full screen map when button tapped

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, mapkit

I would like to display a map in full screen when a button placed on it, is tapped.

My ViewController looks like this (from top to bottom) :
SearchBar
-->Map
-->Tableview

I have set constraints for the map (autoLayout) :

- 0 for leading, trailing, top to Searchbar, bottom to TableView
- 125:49 Ratio

I placed a button on the map and I would like the map to be displayed in full screen when the button is taped.
Then I'd also like the map to retrieve its original constraints when the button is tapped again (map stuck between searchBar and TableView)

How can I accomplish this ?

Thanks !

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I edited my post and added a screenshot. The button is not on the map but I will add it

Comment: This is a very involved question. Do you want to `present` the map modally, `push` it onto the screen, or simply animate it without ever leaving the view controller?

Comment: I don't want to leave the view controller, just to display the map in full screen

Comment: OK, and do you want to animate the map stretching out and filling the screen or perhaps have a new map fade in?

Comment: Exactly ! And add the possibility, when the map is stretched out, to 'cancel' this action

Comment: There are a number of ways you can do this, particularly if the map is in a scroll view (which it looks like it is), but the way that I first try is that when the button is tapped, the contents of the scroll view (excluding the map, of course) are either hidden or the scroll view's offset is adjusted to fit the map in view (scrolling then disabled) and you animate the map's constraint changes to fill the screen. Then the subsequent tap would revert those constraint changes and either reenable scrolling or unhide the rest of the scroll view's contents. This will require real trial and error.

Comment: If change the constraints of the map in order to make it full screen, how can I revert to previous constraints ?

Comment: You have to make the constraints properties of the instance. And in that case you need to make them lazy variables. And you simply activate the default constraints, change them when the button is tapped and animate layoutIfNeeded(). Then when the second button is tapped you deactivate those and re-activate the default constraints and do the same thing.